# How to attach @Step("My step description") annotations to allure report?

Tags: java, aspectj, allure

I am writing an e2e test using @SpringBootTest annotation. I am also using @Autowired test services to process logic during the test. Methods of the test services have @Step() annotation above them with some description of the step.
The issue is that the @Step annotations are not added to allure report by default.

I tried to add aspectjweaver dependency to pom.xml so it could weave those annotations and this solution worked for me, but I could not find a way to limit aspectjweaver to work only with my test classes during test execution and aspectjweaver tried to weave some of source classes and there were several exceptions for some datasources. As long as I need aspectjweaver to only weave @Step annotations for allure, I don't want to configure it for my source code to avoid those exceptions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.